# Paste values as many time as there are filled rows bellow

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I've been trying to find a solution to the following problem for a week but couldn't find anything...

Here is the point ; I've got three different worksheets in my workbook;

- `worksheets("Board")`
- `worksheets("reference")`
- `worksheets("FinalBoard")`

In `worksheets("Board")`   there are multiple column filled with datas with differents headers. I could do a code that paste each datas bellow in sheets("FinalBoard") one bellow the other only if those headers **begin by the value "Fruit"**.

=>`worksheets("Board")`

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit-1 | Fruit-2 | Fruit-3 | Vege-1 |
| x | x | x | Y |
| x | x | x | Y |

here is my code;

Sub test()

```
Worksheets("FinalBoard").Activate
Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim lRowInput As Long
Dim lRowOutput As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Col As String

'~~> Setting sheets
Set wsInput = Sheets("Board")
Set wsOutput = Sheets("FinalBoard")

With wsInput
    '~~> Find last column in Row 2
    lCol = .Cells(2, .columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    
    '~~> Loop through columns
    For i = 1 To lCol
        '~~> Check for my criterias
        If .Cells(2, i).Value2 Like "Fruit*" Then
            '~~> Get column name
            Col = Split(.Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
            
            '~~> Get the last row in that column
            lRowInput = .Range(Col & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
            
            '~~> Find the next row to write to
            If lRowOutput = 0 Then
                lRowOutput = 2
            Else
                lRowOutput = wsOutput.Range("B" & wsOutput.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
            End If
            
            '~~> Copy all datas bellow each headers
            .Range(Col & "3:" & Col & lRowInput).Copy _
            wsOutput.Range("B" & lRowOutput)
        End If
      Next i
```

End With
End Sub

***However, the problem is here*** I'd like to add an extra condition. During this process, if each of these headers match with a cell contained in a list of words in `worksheets("reference")` then copy the value beside that cell(located in column "B") and paste it in `worksheets("Final Board")` in column("A").

=>`worksheets("reference")` ;

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit-1 | N01 |
| Fruit-2 | N02 |
| Fruit-3 | N03 |
| Fruit-4 | N04 |

`worksheets("FinalBoard")` ;
| A | B |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Code | X VALUES |
|   N01 |      x      |
| N02  |      x|
|N03|x|

As soon as I run my code, nothing happens; no message, no error.
I'd also like to insert the following code in the previous I showed you to ease the process and not run this macro again!

Here is it:

```
    Dim wsTEST1, wsTEST2, wsTEST3 As Worksheet
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim i, j, e As Long
    Dim Col As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastlineRef, lastlineDistrib, lastlineResult As Long
  
    
    '~~>  Declaration
    Set wsTEST1 = Sheets("Board")
    
    Set wsTEST2 = Sheets("Reference")
    
    
    Set wsTEST3 = Sheets("FinalBoard")
    
 
   
    With wsTEST1
        
        '~~> loop through columns ( declaration)
        lCol = .Cells(2, .columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
        lastlineRef = Worksheets("Reference").Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        lastlineResult = Worksheets("FinalBoard").Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    
        '~~> loop through columns
        For i = 1 To lCol 'unti last column
            '~~>  research criterias
            If .Cells(2, i).Value Like "Fruit*" Then
                For e = 1 To lastlineResult
                    
                    
                    If wsTEST1.Cells(2, i).Value = Worksheets("Reference").Range("A" & i) Then
                        Worksheets("Reference").Range("A" & e).Offset(, 1).Copy Worksheets("FinalBoard").Range("A" & e)
                     End If
                     
                Next e
            End If
        Next i
        
    End With
end sub
```

I feel like I'm so close to find the correct code... I'd heavily appreciate your help once again ! :)

Comment: Bit hard to follow, but in this line `If wsTEST1.Cells(2, i).Value = Worksheets("Reference").Range("A" & i)` is the problem that `i` doesn't change in this loop so you only check one value in column A?

Comment: From what I undestand, you're trying to: 1\Loop through headers on Sheet1. 2\When header starts with "Fruit", copy "x values" below it in the 1st column of Sheet3. 3\Copy "Nx" values from second column of Sheet2 to second column of Sheet3 with a "Fruit-x" match. Am I correct ? Your code is a bit unclear, and could use some clarification. Using functions such as ```VLookUp``` could help.

Comment: Hello Vincent, yes you understood what I'm trying to do ! The problem is that I dont how to use this function in VBA + repeat the paste of "Nx" values as much as there are "X"values  in sheet3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object) for the lookup.

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet, wsRef As Worksheet
    Dim lRowInput As Long, lRowOutput As Long, iLastRef As Long
    Dim lCol As Long, i As Long, n As Long, s As String

    ' dictionary as look up table
    Dim dict As Object, key As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wsRef = Sheets("reference")
    With wsRef
        iLastRef = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To iLastRef
            key = Trim(.Cells(i, "A"))
            dict(key) = .Cells(i, "B")
        Next
    End With

    '~~> Setting sheets
    Set wsInput = Sheets("Board")
    Set wsOutput = Sheets("FinalBoard")
    lRowOutput = 2
    With wsInput
        ' Find last column in Row 2
        lCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        ' Loop through columns
        For i = 1 To lCol
            '~~> Check for my criterias
            s = Trim(.Cells(2, i).Value2)
            If s Like "Fruit*" Then
                
                ' Get the last row in that column
                lRowInput = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
                n = lRowInput - 2 ' no of rows to copy

                ' Copy all datas bellow each headers
                .Cells(3, i).Resize(n).Copy wsOutput.Range("B" & lRowOutput)

                ' add col A if match
                If dict.exists(s) Then
                    wsOutput.Range("A" & lRowOutput).Resize(n) = dict(s)
                End If

                lRowOutput = lRowOutput + n
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to try it out and tell you asap! Thank you ! :)

Comment: It worked really good ! That's the right answer Thank you !